# Request method is always same when endpoint called using Postman

Tags: spring-boot, postman

Using POSTMANto call an endpoint for example:
`http://localhost/v1`

Checking Request Method in the code using:
`context.getRequest().getMethod()`

No matter what I change request method in postman request, I always get the first request method I select let say GET.

When i change request to
`http://localhost/v1/`
It works and start sending correct request methods i select in POSTMAN

`http://localhost/v1`

I am expecting that when I call:
`http://localhost/v1`
or
`http://localhost/v1/`
It should behave same way.

Any explanation to point to the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need to redirect `/v1` to `/v1/` try like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/v1")
public ModelAndView redirectToPage() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/v1/");
}
```

Comment: Sure, I have a silly question, what is the difference if an endpoint is /v1 and another /v1/ (with leading forward slash)?

Comment: the different you don't have route to handle request for `/v1` and it will return `404`